# Button title uses Storyboard value for half a second instead of using values set in code

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, storyboard

Pretty simple question here:

The scenario is pretty simple: I have a Collection View Cell with 2 buttons set in Storyboard with titles set to the default "Button".

Once I dequeue the cell, I fill in the info, super standard stuff:

```
        let cell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.setTitleButton(buttonText: "text1", buttontext2: "text2")
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
```

Everything works as expected besides the fact that theres like half a second where the buttons title is seen as "Button", then instantly changes to whatever I set it on the setTitleButton method.

Its fixed 100% if I remove the title text completely on Storyboard, but that cant be the only way to solve this, right? I mean doing so completely removes the buttons from the Storyboard (as in its of course still there and accessible via the document outline, but isnt visible at all on the storyboard, which is bad).

I was under the impression that it would ignore the Storyboards value if it was set in code.

After running it a couple times, I realized sometimes it also flashes the value set in code --> sets it as "Button" ---> ends in the value set in code. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
// CollectionViewCell

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    button1.titleLabel?.text = nil
    button2.titleLabel?.text = nil
}
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.button1.setTitle("text1", for: .normal)
    cell.button2.setTitle("text2", for: .normal)
        
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Yup, those changes on awakeFromNib actually do the trick! Thanks! Any clue as to why, though?

Comment: @stompy that's because the app sets everything up from storyboard then runs the code